# XPath - all nodes, but only including the first of a child sequence

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to find XPath (has to be XPath 1.0 due to tools I'm using) which will give me all nodes, but only including the first SCHEME_DOCUMENT :

**Source XML :**

```
<SCHEME_DOCUMENTS INCLUDE_LOOKUPS="N">
  <SCHEME_ID>47</SCHEME_ID>
  <SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT_ID>239</DOCUMENT_ID>
    <FILES>
      <FILE>
        <FILE_ID>441</FILE_ID>
      </FILE>
    </FILES>
  </SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
  <SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT_ID>272</DOCUMENT_ID>
    <FILES>
      <FILE>
        <FILE_ID>444</FILE_ID>
      </FILE>
      <FILE>
        <FILE_ID>445</FILE_ID>
        <RECIPIENTS>
          <RECIPIENT>
            <ORG_CONTACT_ID>267</ORG_CONTACT_ID>
          </RECIPIENT>
        </RECIPIENTS>
      </FILE>
    </FILES>
  </SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
</SCHEME_DOCUMENTS>
```

**This is what I want :**

```
<SCHEME_DOCUMENTS INCLUDE_LOOKUPS="N">
  <SCHEME_ID>47</SCHEME_ID>
  <SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT_ID>239</DOCUMENT_ID>
    <FILES>
      <FILE>
        <FILE_ID>441</FILE_ID>
      </FILE>
    </FILES>
  </SCHEME_DOCUMENT>
</SCHEME_DOCUMENTS>
```

Comment: you can select with xpath, but not filter retaining `root` node. What's your OS and programming language?

Comment: You need to use XSLT if you want to include only first SCHEME_DOCUMENT